# How to compile libcurl with ssl by using MinGW

Tags: c, windows, ssl, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to send an email in c. I want to use libcurl for that. But before i need to understand how it's working.

So i [download curl-7.63.0.zip](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and [MinGW32](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/).
After installing MinGW, i select all the basic package :

- mingw-developper-toolkit-bin
- mingw32-base-bin
- mingw32-gcc-fortran-bi
- mingw32-gcc-g++-bin
- mingw32-gcc-objc-bin msys-base-bin

In next, i have extracted all the files to a folder and i run a cmd to write

```
\>cd "something\curl-7.63.0"
\>mingw32-make mingw32-ssl
```

But i recieve an error :

```
\>D:\Projets_Info\Emails\Méthode n°8 Libcurl\drivers\curl-7.63.0>mingw32-make mingw32-ssl
mingw32-make -C lib -f Makefile.m32 CFG=mingw32-ssl
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Projets_Info/Emails/Méthode n°8
Libcurl/drivers/curl-7.63.0/lib'
Makefile.m32:257: *** Invalid path to OpenSSL package: ../../openssl-1.0.2a.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Projets_Info/Emails/Méthode n°8 Libcurl/drivers/curl-7.63.0/lib'
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'mingw32-ssl' failed
mingw32-make: *** [mingw32-ssl] Error 2
```

Does anyone has an idea ? An idea that permit me to have curl with ssl

Comment: Do you have this path on your machine `../../openssl-1.0.2a` ?

Comment: Seems like it should be `D:/Projets_Info/Emails/Méthode n°8 Libcurl/drivers/openssl-1.0.2a`

Comment: Thanks you; I download an other package with this file.

Comment: Now i have to find how to use it. If you have an exemple, can you share it to me ?

Comment: You could look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/ which also uses libcurl (when not built in the light version)